# Using QLineEdit.setText() freezes the window but background tasks works fine

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, pyqt5

I am trying to create a chatroom program as a casual project to better understand PyQt5 and multi-threading, but I am facing rather strange problem. Inside ***sWindow*** class, in the ***createserver()* function**, ***setText()* in the display widget in the *try* block freezes the screen but the background processes work fine. *setText* function in the *except* block works fine. If I try to print the statements to the cmd, it works perfectly.**

Here is the code snippet where I am facing the problem:

```
def createServer(self):
    try:
        self.display.setText("Creating server") #doesn't display text, whole screen freezes
        print("Creating Server") #works fine
        self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.s.listen(10)
        print("Server Created") #works fine
        self.display.append("Server Created.") #doesn't print anything
        self.display.append("Started listening to clients")
        self.Listen() #goes into the listen function as well without display widget printing anything
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        self.display.setText("Error occured")
```

Here is the whole code:

```
class sWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, title = "File Sharing", l = 0, t = 0, r = 800, b = 600):
    super().__init__()
    self.left = l
    self.right = r
    self.top = t
    self.bottom = b
    self.title = title
    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.host = ""
    self.port = 15478
    self.ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
    self.initUi()
    self.shutting = False
    self.mode = 0
    self.address = {}
    self.clientaddr = {}
    self.buffsize = 2048
    self.encoding = 'utf8'




def closeEvent(self, event):
    reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Message Box", "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.shutting = True
        self.s.close()
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()


def createServer(self):
    try:
        self.display.setText("Creating server")
        print("Creating Server")
        self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.s.listen(10)
        print("Server Created")
        self.display.append("Server Created.")
        self.display.append("Started listening to clients")
        self.Listen()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        self.display.setText("Error occured")


def Listen(self):
    try:
        print("started listenting")
        while self.shutting == False:
            client, addr = self.s.accept()
            self.address[client] = addr
            message = "Enter your name: "
            client.send(message.encode(encoding))
            threading.Thread(target = handleclient, args = (client,)).start()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error occured while creating server. ',e)



def handleclient(self, client):
    try: 
        name = client.recv(buffsize).decode(encoding)
        self.display.append(name + " connected from address ", addr)
        self.clientaddr[client] = name
        message = "Welcome " + name + "!! You have entered the chatroom."
        client.send(message.encode(encoding))
        message = name + "has entered the chatroom. "
        self.broadcast(message, client)
        while self.shutting == False:
            data = client.recv(buffsize).decode(encoding)
            self.display.append(name + ': ' + data)
            self.broadcast(data, client)


    except Exception as e:
        del self.address[client]
        del self.clientaddr[client]
        self.display.append('Error occured while connecting to client. ',e)
        message = name + " entered the chatroom."
        self.broadcast(message.encode(encoding), False)
        return


def broadcast(self, mesage, client):
    try:
        for sock in self.address.keys():
            if sock != client:
                sock.send(message)
    except Exception as e:
        self.display.append("Error occured while broadcasting the message to clients. ", e)
        print(e)
        return




def centr(self):
    qr = self.frameGeometry()
    cr = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cr)
    self.move(qr.topLeft())

def initUi(self):
    ## For window

    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.right, self.bottom)
    self.centr()
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("fSharing.jpg"))

    ## For layout

    self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
    self.grid = QGridLayout()
    self.grid.setSpacing(10)
    self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.grid)

#def createServer(self):


def mainWindow(self):
    ## buttons
    global ip
    self.connect = QPushButton("Connect")
    self.connect.setToolTip("Connect to the server")
    self.connect.resize(self.connect.sizeHint())

    self.create = QPushButton("Create Server")
    self.create.setToolTip("Create server for others to connect")
    self.create.resize(self.create.sizeHint())
    self.create.clicked.connect(self.createServer)

    self.chooseFile = QPushButton("Choose File")
    self.chooseFile.setToolTip("Choose the file you want to send.")
    self.chooseFile.setEnabled(False)
    self.chooseFile.resize(self.chooseFile.sizeHint())

    self.send = QPushButton("Send")
    self.send.setEnabled(False)
    self.send.resize(self.send.sizeHint())

    self.sendFile = QPushButton("Send File")
    self.sendFile.setToolTip("Send the selected file")
    self.sendFile.setEnabled(False)
    self.sendFile.resize(self.sendFile.sizeHint())


    ## text Fields

    self.ip = QLineEdit()
    self.ip.setPlaceholderText("Ex: 192.168.0.1")

    self.display = QTextEdit()
    self.display.setReadOnly(True)

    self.sendText = QTextEdit()

    ## Label

    self.lbl = QLabel()
    self.lbl.setText(" Or ")

    self.grid.addWidget(self.create, 0,3 )
    self.grid.addWidget(self.lbl, 0,5)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.ip, 0,7)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.connect,0,9)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.display, 1, 1, 8, 7)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.chooseFile, 2, 9)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.sendFile, 4, 9)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.sendText, 9, 1, 2, 7)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.send, 9,9)
    self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = sWindow()
    win.mainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt to be able to handle the events and tasks that need to be done, create an event loop, in a simple description the event loop is a while True within which it reviews the different events such as the mouse, keyboard, events created by the user, etc. And you create your server by creating a loop that blocks the event loop, and that consequently means that the GUI can not handle those tasks and freeze as you signal.

Like you are creating threads so that communication with clients does not block the server the same should be done with the server with respect to the GUI, but this brings with it an inconvenience: the GUI can not be updated from another thread (in your case `self.display.setText()` or `self.display.append()` redraw the text of the GUI), Qt recommends using signals, and for that it is better to separate, in this case I have created a Manager class that inherits from `QObject` so that it can create the signals and administer the server:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Manager(QObject):
    logSignal = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.address = {}
        self.clientaddr = {}
        self.shutting = False
        self.encoding = 'utf8'
        self.buffsize = 2048

    def create_server(self, host, port):
        try:
            self.logSignal.emit("Creating server")
            print("Creating Server")
            self.s.bind((host, port))
            self.s.listen(10)
            print("Server Created")
            self.logSignal.emit("Server Created.")
            self.logSignal.emit("Started listening to clients")
            self.listen()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            self.logSignal.emit("Error occured")

    def listen(self):
        try:
            print("started listenting")
            while self.shutting == False:
                client, addr = self.s.accept()
                self.address[client] = addr
                message = "Enter your name: "
                client.send(message.encode(self.encoding))
                threading.Thread(target =self.handleclient, args = (client,), daemon=True).start()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error occured while creating server. ',e)

    def handleclient(self, client):
        try: 
            name = client.recv(self.buffsize).decode(self.encoding)
            self.logSignal.emit(name + " connected from address " + str(self.address[client]))
            self.clientaddr[client] = name
            message = "Welcome " + name + "!! You have entered the chatroom."
            client.send(message.encode(self.encoding))
            message = name + "has entered the chatroom. "
            self.broadcast(message, client)
            while self.shutting == False:
                data = client.recv(self.buffsize).decode(self.encoding)
                self.logSignal.emit(name + ': ' + data)
                self.broadcast(data, client)

        except Exception as e:
            del self.address[client]
            del self.clientaddr[client]
            self.logSignal.emit('Error occured while connecting to client. ' + str(e))
            message = name + " entered the chatroom."
            self.broadcast(message.encode(self.encoding), False)

    def broadcast(self, mesage, client):
        try:
            for sock in self.address.keys():
                if sock != client:
                    sock.send(message)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logSignal.emit("Error occured while broadcasting the message to clients. ", e)
            print(e)

    def stop(self):
        self.shutting = True
        self.s.close()

class sWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, title = "File Sharing"):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

        self.port = 15478
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.manager.logSignal.connect(self.display.append)

    def initUi(self):
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("File Sharing")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("fSharing.jpg"))
        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget())
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.connect = QPushButton("Connect")
        self.connect.setToolTip("Connect to the server")
        self.connect.resize(self.connect.sizeHint())

        self.create = QPushButton("Create Server")
        self.create.setToolTip("Create server for others to connect")
        self.create.resize(self.create.sizeHint())
        self.chooseFile = QPushButton("Choose File")
        self.chooseFile.setToolTip("Choose the file you want to send.")
        self.chooseFile.setEnabled(False)
        self.chooseFile.resize(self.chooseFile.sizeHint())

        self.send = QPushButton("Send")
        self.send.setEnabled(False)
        self.send.resize(self.send.sizeHint())

        self.sendFile = QPushButton("Send File")
        self.sendFile.setToolTip("Send the selected file")
        self.sendFile.setEnabled(False)

        self.ip = QLineEdit()
        self.ip.setPlaceholderText("Ex: 192.168.0.1")

        self.display = QTextEdit()
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)

        self.sendText = QTextEdit()

        self.lbl = QLabel()
        self.lbl.setText(" Or ")

        self.grid.addWidget(self.create, 0,3 )
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lbl, 0,5)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.ip, 0,7)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.connect,0,9)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.display, 1, 1, 8, 7)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.chooseFile, 2, 9)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.sendFile, 4, 9)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.sendText, 9, 1, 2, 7)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.send, 9,9)
        self.centr()

        self.create.clicked.connect(self.on_create)

    def on_create(self):
        threading.Thread(target = self.manager.create_server, daemon=True, args = (self.ip.text(), self.port)).start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Message Box", "Are you sure?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.manager.stop()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def centr(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cr = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cr)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = sWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

---

Note: On the other hand if you do not want to deal with the threads Qt offers classes such as `QTcpServer` and `QTcpSocket` to handle the connections without blocking the event loop in a Qt-friendly way. You can find an example of a chat made with those classes: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-network-chat-connection-cpp.html